# How to get Spring WebContext in class annotated @controller

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, autowired, applicationcontext

In Spring MVC with annotation, we mark any POJO with @Controller. 
In this controller we can get WebApplicationContext, using autowired property.

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext act;

    @RequestMapping("/*.html")
    public String handleBasic(){
        SimpleDomain sd = (SimpleDomain)act.getBean("sd1");
        System.out.println(sd.getFirstProp());
        return "hello";
}
```

But in this approach we do not have servletContext handy with us. So is there way we can still use older way of getting WebApplicationContext ? i.e.

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)
```

How will we get servletContext here ?

I am not facing any compulsion to use old way; so this question is just out of curiosity to check flexibility of spring. 
Also It can be a interview question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just inject it into your controller:

```
@Autowired private ServletContext servletContext;
```

Or take HttpServletRequest as a parameter and get it from there:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView myMethod(HttpServletRequest request ...){
    ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext()
}
```

Comment: request doesn't have getServletContext(), request.getSession().getServletContext() will work

Comment: @itsraja in fact, `HttpServletRequest` has that method, inherited from [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).

Comment: @Raj that method exists way before than Servlet 3.0

Answer (score 2):

The following is correct approach :

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

Otherwise instead of auto wiring the ServletContext, you can implement ServletContextAware. Spring will notice this when running in a web application context and inject the ServletContext. Read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it inline:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demp", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String demo(@RequestBody String request) {
    HttpServletRequest re3 = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder

            .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    return "sfsdf";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an Interface from Spring called `org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware`

```
public class MyController implements ServletContextAware {
    private ServletContext servletContext; 

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
       this.servletContext=servletContext;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `servletContext` any place in the class.

Answer (score 1):

By accessing the session you can get the servlet context, sample code:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

....
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView myMethod(HttpSession session ...){

WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext())

}

}
```

You can get the HttpSession from the HttpServletRequest also.